# IntelliJ: view property values in code

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, properties-file, code-folding

In newer versions of IntelliJ, value of properties used in `@Value` annotation (and maybe in other contexts) are shown like this:

[image]

This doesn't work if you have clicked on the preview or because sometimes IntelliJ ignores it:

[image]

How is it possible to force IntelliJ show the property value?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Place the caret on the key inside `@Value` annotation and press `Ctrl` + `-` shortcut.
To do the reverse (show the key), either click on the value preview or press `Ctrl` + `+` shortcut.

I find this `Ctrl` + `-` shortcut to be very useful to fold any code block; for example you can use it inside a Javadoc to collapse it altogether.